# Getting Error on Importing Custom Fonts using SASS

Tags: css, sass, font-face, truetype

I am using Sass for my project and I am getting this error on my home page while importing fonts from my custom fonts folder of Merriweather.The problem is that when i check the network tab on chrome it shows that Agenda font file is included but not the merriweather font file.Both Agenda and Merriweather fonts are in separate folders.

**Error :**

**`**http://localhost/project-name/fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Italic.tff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**`**

**My Project folder structure in like this:**

- project-folder/fonts-folder/Merriweather-folder/All fonts of Merriweather here
- project-folder/fonts-folder/Agenda-folder/All fonts of Agenda here
- project-folder/scss-folder/partials-folder/global.scss
- project-folder/scss-folder/variables.scss

**QUESTIONS:**

- I want to know the is my syntax right for importing multiple fonts
  from the same font family like Merriweather ?
- what exactly i am doing wrong in variables.scss ??

  Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Code in Variables.scss**

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: Agenda;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/Agenda/Agenda-Medium.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Merriweather-Italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url("../fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Italic.tff") format("truetype");
}


@font-face {
    font-family: Merriweather-Regular;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Regular.tff") format("truetype");
}
```

**This is how i am using fonts in globals.scss**

```
@import "../variables";

body{

    font-family: Merriweather-Regular;
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: $white;

}

h1{
    font-family: Merriweather-Italic;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 94px;
}

h2{
    font-family: Merriweather-Regular,Merriweather-Italic;
    font-size: 42px;
}

h3{
    font-family: Agenda;
    font-size: 30px;
}

h4{
    font-family: Merriweather-Regular;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 27px;
}

h5{
    font-family: Merriweather-Regular;
    font-size: 26px;
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure I would have to see a screenshot of your `fonts` folder, but I think the font isn't found because of typo in the font-face declaration. True-type font files usually have a `.ttf` extension instead of `.tff`.

That means you would have to adjust your `@font-face` declaration from:

```
@font-face {
   // omitted font-family, weight and style for clarity
   src: url("../fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Italic.tff") format("truetype");
}
```

to:

```
@font-face {
   // omitted font-family, weight and style for clarity
   src: url("../fonts/Merriweather/Merriweather-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

At this point, so in `variables.scss`, I usually also declare a font variable for each font (type) for usage in the rest of my SASS files, e.g `$merriweather--italic: "Merriweather-Italic", serif;`

Therefore you can use these variables in your `global.scss` as such:

```
h1{
  font-family: $merriweather--italic;
  font-size: 94px;
}
```

Comment: you are right !! i was using the wrong extension..
Thanks alot for giving your answer in detail...Really appreciate it